# Not able to redirect to url of ejs file to router defined in js file having two parameters

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, ejs

I am working in node js and ejs file.
In router i am expecting two parameters as below line

```
router.get('/pettycashlistview/:expenseId&:isDisabled',verify,(request, 
response) => {
```

one is expense id and another one is isDisabled as i am passing both parameters through a file and below line

```
pettyCashTableRows += '<tr><td colspan="4"><center><a target="_blank" 
href="/expense/pettycashlistview/'+expenseId+'&'+buttonDisable+'" 
>View All</a></center></td></tr>';
```

I want to pass same thing through ejs as the below line:

```
<a class="btn btn-primary btn-md bg-gray mb-mobile" 
href="/expense/pettycashlistview?expenseId=<%= parentExpenseId %>" 
id="createNewPettyCashButton">Go To Petty Cash</a>
```

How can i acheive the same thing for last line and what parameters i need to define that i should not get error buttonDisable is not defined.
How can I pass two parameters for

```
<a class="btn btn-primary btn-md bg-gray mb-mobile"  
href="/expense/pettycashlistview?expenseId=<%= parentExpenseId %>" 
id="createNewPettyCashButton">Go To Petty Cash</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

generally I would split seperate parameters and not try to join them.

`/pettycashlistview/:expenseId/:isDisabled` would give you two seperate keys in the `req.params` object, one called `expenseId` and another called `isDisabled`.

You may need to parse the params to the correct datatype after extracting them from the `req.params` object (i.e. cast the `isDisabled` property to a boolean)